# R remove objects without throwing an error if they don't exist

Tags: r, dataframe

Within a loop, I try to remove a list of data frames simply with

```
rm(a,b,c,d)
```

However, in case an data-frame (e.g. `b`) does not exist in the global environment, I get a warning

```
In rm(a,b,c,d,...:
  object 'b' not found
```

How can I suppress this warning to not pop-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `suppressWarnings`

```
suppressWarnings(rm(a,b,c,d))
```

Comment: The OP had the answer staring at him in the face!

Comment: @Edward haha, yes! :)

Answer (score 1):

@RonakShah has the correct answer here, though it is possible to avoid generating a warning at all by defining a function that checks for the existence of variables before trying to remove them:

```
rm2 <- function(...) 
{ 
  names <- sapply(as.list(match.call()[-1]), deparse); 
  rm(list = names[sapply(names, exists)], envir = parent.frame())
}
```

So you can do:

```
x <- 1; y <- 2;
ls()
#> [1] "rm2" "x"   "y"

rm2(x, y, z) # Note no warning generated since no attempt made to remove z

ls()
[1] "rm2"
```